# Proposal: new sites can tune the semantics of 'Communty Wiki'

Tags: feature-request, area-51

Here's my proposal:

As part of defining a new site, the following could be decided:

1. Will there be 'community wiki' at all?
2. What string will label it?
3. Does checking the box turn off rep?
4. Does checking the box change edit rep thresholds?

(Further, it seems to me that all the rep thresholds should be under the control of the site's diamonds, but that's perhaps another story.)

Comment: FYI, Inward Quest tuned CW by changing their policy and by convention. See http://groups.google.com/group/inward-quest-discussions/browse_thread/thread/c0e42a21b28e160f, and an example CW post: http://www.inwardquest.com/questions/5633/the-symphony-of-science-project. Note the header placed at the top of the page indicating community wiki status and why.  InwardQuest is a website where essentially *every* question is subjective, and they have managed to build a thriving community.